# Can I safely charge an iPhone 4S with a 5V 2A source?

Tags: battery, iphone, power, charging

I just bought a [New Trent IMP99D](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002YFDRHW) external battery, to keep my phone alive while gaming during long-haul flights. It has two USB ports to connect to, one which supplies 1 amp at 5 volts, another which supplies 2 amps at 5 volts.

The instruction manual says to connect smartphones to the 1-amp port, and any iPad 2's to the 2-amp port.

Is there any harm, or do I incur any inefficiencies, if I connect my iPhone 4S to the 2-amp port instead of the recommended 1-amp port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I travel, I only bring my iPad charger and use it interchangeably with my iPhone 4 without noticing any battery life performance and by that extension it should be the same for iPhone 4s.

Apple's [website](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC359LL/A) seems to confirm this; For the 10W USB iPad charger - "It also charges iPhone and all iPod models with a dock connector."

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, the iPhone has built in safeguards and  using the iPad charger wont incur any real damage

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add a citation for this?

Answer (score -1):

It will destroy your battery if you do that for a long time... Mine exploded when I plugged it in after a while of using it! CAUTION!!!!